# Taking web page screen shot in Windows 8 Metro app

Tags: c#, screenshot, windows-8, microsoft-metro, webpage-screenshot

I'm trying to take screen shot of web page in Windows 8 Metro app. So far the only helpful control is the `WebView`. Unfortunately it does not contain any method like `DrawToBitmap` (known from Forms `WebBrowser` control). Am I missing something?

Different approach would focus on injecting some JS (e.g. html2canvas) to page rendered in `WebView` but I don't think it is possible due to security reasons. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebViewBrush is like WebView except its non-interactive and its a brush so you can render it wherever you want