# display html in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I wasted few hours for looking the answer and I'm very sad cause I didn't find anything usefull. I have a CMS in cloud and it provides content for diffrent devices like www site and my new windows store application.
I want to use html formating. I've already created app in c# and xaml and I'm wondering how can I display html

I was happy cause I found http://nuget.org/packages/RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml but I can't make it work. I get blank page. No text, no error, no nothing.

Can someone pls tell me how can I display html in my app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a WebView/WebViewBrush or use HTML Agility Pack and implement the styles/rendering yourself.

Comment: doesn`t WebView display pages from external sources ? I have my Model with field Body that contains html String. How can I bind it to WebView ?

Answer (score 0):

In WinRt app you can display html code by some ways:

- Using WebView with it's NavigateToString("html content")
- Using WebViewBrush and displaying it in rectangle
- If you had your .html file local - you can open it with `myWebview.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///" + myPath));`
- You can make a screenshot of webpage by the method wich I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869318/taking-web-page-screen-shot-in-windows-8-metro-app/17276603#17276603) and open it as a picture.

For more info, see the [WebView control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)